# ft2build.h: No such file or directory - Freetype 2.6

Tags: c++, qt, jenkins, qmake

I am trying to build from Linux cause I decided to start using Jenkins, my personal work but, even with freetype installed: v.2.6.3, it doens't recognize this ft2build.h.

This is the QT Pro with freetype loaded. I'm now running on UBuntu 16.04:

```
linux {
    message("Build for Linux")
    DEFINES += LINUX
    DEFINES += BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK
    LIBS += -lGLU
    LIBS += -lfreetype
    LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/-libboost_timer.so -libboost_log.so -libboost_log_setup.so -libboost_system.so -libboost_thread.so -libboost_filesystem.so
}
```

So i tried to change also the lib pointer doing manually as:

```
LIBS *= -L/usr/local/lib/ -lfreetype
```

but still nothing going properly. The error I get is from lGLU

```
In file included from displays/display.cpp:3:0:
displays/./../oglft/oglft.h:50:22: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:1093: recipe for target 'display.o' failed
```

I do always run 'qmake make clean' then /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake && make && make check to be sure it starts properly. Can someone help me solving the bug?

I've checked where freetype lib is located by doing:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs freetype2
```

and this is what I get

```
-I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -L/usr/local/lib -lfreetype
```

Comment: You should find full path of library first. Can you share output of "find / -type f -name  ft2build.h" command?

Comment: @AliOkanYüksel

/usr/local/include/freetype2/ft2build.h
/usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h

Comment: You should find CC variable in Makefile and you should append "-I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -L/usr/local/lib" parameters to CC command variable.

Comment: @AliOkanYüksel Done still same error!
Appreciate your help anyway!

Comment: Did you run "make clean" first?

Comment: Yes sure. make clean then I edited the Makefile then i run qmake && make && make check but same error.
@AliOkanYüksel

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

I have had to set FREETYPE in the environment variables as BOOST too and everything is now working properly!
Here is how is mine:

```
export BOOST=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/boost_1_59_0
export FREETYPE=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/freetype-2.6.3
```

I preferred to move those two libs under Jenkins to avoid permissions problems.

;-)